# How do I filter the "admin/content" page through it's url?

Tags: nodes

As the content overview page ("admin/content") has filtering capabilities, I'm trying to allow my users to access the filtered content through an url.

For example, if I want to see a list of contents of type "Article", I would like to access "admin/content/article" or a similar url, and get the contents page with the filter already applied.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default this is not possible.
Easiest I can see would be to create a view - if you have views module installed - that has the same path which will override the default Drupal content screen.

Then you can either create argument for the content type as part of url and/or expose filters and since the filters are being passed via get parameter, you will be able to construct an url to point to the filter selection.

Which is almost what [administration views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views) module does. You might want to extend these views with arguments, filters, etc...

Other option would be to create custom functionality that would "hook" into the default functionality.

Comment: Administration views and a contextual filter did the job in a couple of minutes. Thank you!